# $_SESSION variables not working, not working in other pages

Tags: php, session

I have created the session at

**LOGIN PAGE**

```
   <?php
session_start();
include 'dbconfig.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username' AND password= '$password' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['user'];
        echo $_SESSION["userid"];
    }
} else {
    echo "wrong";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**FETCHING LOGIN**

```
function login() {

    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (username == "" || username == null || username == undefined || password == "" || password == null || password == undefined) {
        $('#foremptyvalue').show();
    } else {
        $('#foremptyvalue').hide();
        $('#loader').show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: baseurl + "login.php"
            , data: 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password
            , type: "POST"
            , success: function (response) {
                response = $.trim(response);
                if (response == "wrong") {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                    $('#forwronginput').show();
                    $("#username").val('');
                    $("#password").val('');
                } else {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                    $('#forwronginput').hide();
                    location.href = "account.php?id=" + response;
                }

            }
            , error: function () {}
        });
    }

}
```

**HEADER.PHP**

In this page the session variable is not working.
I have used below code:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
$session = $_SESSION["userid"];
?>
```

RESULT IS BELOW

> ptarbkn67poq1gkch2dh6fvqc3 **Notice**:  Undefined index: userid in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\feescounter\header.php** on line **4**

I have also check whether the session save path is writable or not and it is writable.
it is saving the session in C:\xampp\tmp

Comment: Use session_start() in LOGIN PAGE

Comment: used still it is giving me same error

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Have you wrote it at the top of the page?

Comment: You need to use `session_start();` in each page where you wan to use the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: header.php is included in every page and I used session_start() in header .php

Comment: Side note, don't do this: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username' AND password= '$password' ";`, it is an sql injection waiting to happen.

Comment: You wrote echo $_SESSION["userid"]; in login page. Have you got value in that page?

Comment: @RaviHirani I have updated the question please check

Comment: Side note, don't store passwords as plaintext (`$password = $_POST['password'];`)

Comment: @RaviHirani Yes, i am getting the value on login page

Comment: User logged in at the time when you are testing right? Sorry if I sounds so stupid

Comment: write print_r($_SESSION); and show your output in header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must start the Session before using it. It doesn't seem that way from your code...
Try putting the code below at the very top of each of your Files and see how it goes:

```
    <?php
    // THIS SHOULD BE THE VERY FIRST LINES OF CODE IN YOUR SCRIPTS
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your header.php file should be:-

```
<?php
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

if(!empty($_SESSION['userid'])){
   echo $_SESSION['userid'];
}else{
   echo 'guest user';
}
```